# Installing surround.vim plugin into Vim's plugins folder seems to have no effect?

Tags: vim, plugins, surround

I've downloaded the surround plugin (surround.vim) for [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and installed it into the plugins folder. I know plugins work there as i've successfully installed the NERDTree and TList plugins.

Once surround is installed, i start Vim and enter insert mode <kbd>i</kbd> and type:

> "Hello World!"

I then go to normal mode <kbd>Esc</kbd> and move the cursor into the text and press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> and nothing happens!

I've also tried deleting the surrounds using <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> and still nothing happens.

Have you any idea why this plugin is not working? Do i have to initialise it in the `_gvimrc` file? Could another plugin conflict with this one?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: why not use pathogen? avoid that "where should I place what" confusion, and written by the same guy who wrote surround

Comment: surround works for me on windows gvim

Comment: Check `:scriptnames` to see that it's actually being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to sa125's answer i installed the [Pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) plugin manager and the troubles disappeared. It must of been something conflicting.